# Xpath: select following until node

Tags: xpath

In Xpath i need to select `<p>` nodes following the `<h2>DATA</h2>` nodes until next `<h2>`, so in a structure like:

```
<div class="box">
    <h2>NO</h2>
    <p>B:<span> Y</span></p>
    <h2>DATA</h2>
    <p>AA:<span> CONTENT</span></p>
    <p>AA:<span> MORE</span></p>
    <h2>NO</h2>
    <p>C:<span> Z</span></p>
    <h2>DATA</h2>
    <p>BB:<span> CONTENT</span></p>
    <p>BB:<span> MORE</span></p>
</div>
```

should select:

```
    <p>AA:<span> CONTENT</span></p>
    <p>AA:<span> MORE</span></p>
    <p>BB:<span> CONTENT</span></p>
    <p>BB:<span> MORE</span></p>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about this?

```
p[preceding-sibling::h2[1][.="DATA"]]
```

---

My python test for checking the xpath I provided:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> doc = etree.XML("""<div class="box">
...     <h2>NO</h2>
...     <p>B:<span> Y</span></p>
...     <h2>DATA</h2>
...     <p>AA:<span> CONTENT</span></p>
...     <p>AA:<span> MORE</span></p>
...     <h2>NO</h2>
...     <p>C:<span> Z</span></p>
...     <h2>DATA</h2>
...     <p>BB:<span> CONTENT</span></p>
...     <p>BB:<span> MORE</span></p>
... </div>""")
>>> doc.xpath('p[preceding-sibling::h2[1][.="DATA"]]')
[<Element p at 252ef70>, <Element p at 252efc8>, <Element p at 2542050>, <Element p at 25420a8>]
>>> doc.xpath('p[preceding-sibling::h2[1][.="DATA"]]/text()')
['AA:', 'AA:', 'BB:', 'BB:']
```

Comment: Oh, i talked too much soon. This only works if the h2 position is [1]. If there is more than one <h2>DATA<h2> in the structure wont select the following nodes.

Comment: This still produces the desired results for your updated sample for me

Comment: @TMichel The expression (when prefixed by `//`) basically says: Find me all `p` elements so that their first `h2` sibling has `DATA`. That is a correct expression and still gives the right results for your input.

Comment: True. Just realized that the original data is malformed so your solution is definetively right. Thanks again.